# Can't run deferred tasks

Tags: python, google-app-engine

This is how I add a task on the task queue

```
                    taskqueue.Task(url='/worker',
                               params={"json_records": jsonified_task_records,
                                       "user": user.key.urlsafe()}
                               ).add(queue_name='postios')
```

Then in the unit test I run the view that pushes the task in the task queue.  Now I would like to execute the actual task:

```
rv = self.client.post('api/v1.0/ftrecords/device_id/123', headers=headers, data=json.dumps(records))
            # Get the task out of the queue
            tasks = self.taskqueue_stub.get_filtered_tasks()
            self.assertEqual(1, len(tasks))
            # Run the task
            task = tasks[0]
            deferred.run(task.payload)
```

This however throws an exception in deferred lib:

```
def run(data):
  """Unpickles and executes a task.

  Args:
    data: A pickled tuple of (function, args, kwargs) to execute.
  Returns:
    The return value of the function invocation.
  """
  try:
    func, args, kwds = pickle.loads(data)
  except Exception, e:
    raise PermanentTaskFailure(e)
  else:
    return func(*args, **kwds)
```

I commented out the exception around 'pickle.loads()' to get a better stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/hooman/workspace/F11A/src/tests/test_rest_records.py", line 451, in test_post_updated_records_new_timestamp
    deferred.run(task.payload)
  File "/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/google/appengine/ext/deferred/deferred.py", line 142, in run
    func, args, kwds = pickle.loads(data)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1382, in loads
    return Unpickler(file).load()
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 858, in load
    dispatch[key](self)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1161, in load_long_binget
    self.append(self.memo[repr(i)])
KeyError: '1601073011'
```

I am running the latest 1.9.7.  Any idea what could be wrong please?

Comment: The task cannot load your pickled params (jsonified_task_records). So search  for: "app engine task pickle keyerror" and your jsonified_task_records

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I found this but it says use deferred lib, which I am already using. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4836697/google-app-engine-payload-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The deferred package is an alternative to adding tasks to the queue directly, but you're mixing them together - deferred.run is expecting to deal with something added using deferred.defer, so either use that to add your task, or have your test run your /worker URL directly.